# Unable to load variables stored in a file in scala, through a variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to load a scala file from filesystem, in spark shell, using:

:load "path of the file"

This works well->

```
scala> :load /User/Mohit/file.scala
Loading /User/Mohit/file.scala...
data_site: String = http://download.cms.gov/
download_file_name: String = data.zip
database_table: String = NPES
data_main_file: String = data_pfile
data_prac_loc: String = pl_pfile_
data_other_name: String = othername_pfile_
data_exclusion: String = FileHeader.csv
checking: String = checked
```

but when I am trying to load this path via variable, its giving me below error :

```
scala> val check = "/User/Mohit/file.scala"
check: String = /User/Mohit/file.scala

scala> :load check
That file does not exist
```

**Note: The file actually exists**

Any help towards this would be appreciable please.

Comment: If your using Linux, open terminal and using a editor, for example nano, open the file: `nano /User/Mohit/file.scala` and see if it detect the file?

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani .. Yes, it does detect the file

Comment: check the Uppercase and Lowercase in your path and try `:load check.trim`

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani The problem is more fundamental—see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't exactly possible, since the `:load` command in the REPL doesn't take a `String` as an argument, and in fact is not an ordinary Scala method (like we would have if we defined `def load(in: String) = ???` in the REPL) at all. The colon indicates that it's a REPL command, and the arguments of REPL commands aren't evaluated as Scala code, so the `check` here is just the file name `check`, not the Scala variable you've defined.

It is possible to load a file programmatically like this, but it's a little trickier, and the approach isn't guaranteed to work across Scala versions. If you have a file `foo.scala` in the current directory like this:

```
val message = "hello world"

println(message)
```

Then you can do the following in a REPL:

```
scala> val fooSource = "foo.scala"
fooSource: String = foo.scala

scala> :power
Power mode enabled. :phase is at typer.
import scala.tools.nsc._, intp.global._, definitions._
Try :help or completions for vals._ and power._

scala> r.loadCommand(fooSource)
Loading foo.scala...
message: String = hello world
hello world
res0: $r.r.Result = Result(true,Some(:load foo.scala))

scala> message
res2: String = hello world
```

…where `r` is a special variable introduced by `:power` that gives you programmatic access to the REPL's interactive loop. I've done this before when I wanted to open a bunch of generated source files in the REPL without typing out all the names, but in general it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: This worked!! you saved my day Travis, thanks a lot for your help here :)